# Sympy: Probability measure of a set

Tags: python, sympy, probability

While trying to calculate a probability of a bounded set like this:

```
from sympy.stats import Normal, P
from sympy import  Interval
n = Normal("n", 0, 1)
P(n in Interval(-1, 1))
```

I'm getting the following error:

`TypeError: did not evaluate to a bool: (-1 <= n) & (n <= 1)`
How to deal with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `Interval()` you have to call its `contains()` method:

```py
P(Interval(-1,1).contains(n))
```

as the documentation states on using `in` with `Interval()` ([here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html)):

> As a shortcut it is possible to use the ‘in’ operator, but that will raise an error unless an affirmative true or false is not obtained. [..] The result of ‘in’ is a bool, not a SymPy value.

Alternatively, you can directly formulate the conditions inside the probability function:

```py
P((n >-1) & (n<1))
```